# Crystal Reports: Suppression is hiding records on the next page

Tags: crystal-reports, suppression

I have a Crystal Report where I want to display only the first ItemNum row.

I used the following expression (?) to suppress subsequent records.

`Previous ({ItemHistory.ItemNum}) = ({ItemHistory.ItemNum})`

My problem is that when I use a parameter selecting only one ItemNum, the same ItemNum on the second page which I want to appear (because it belongs to a different storeroom) will also be suppressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I just added check to make sure supression of the ItemNum on the next page (new storeroom) is not performed.

```
Previous ({ItemHistory.ItemNum}) = 
{ItemHistory.ItemNum} 
and 
Previous({ITEMHISTORY.STOREROOM}) = 
{ITEMHISTORY.STOREROOM}
```